# add object property into map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

`this.users = this.users.map(oldUser => oldUser.id === user.id ? user : oldUser);`

above code is to splice in updated user's data into users object, but in the same time I also wanted to add extra property into user object, I tried

```
this.users = this.users.map(oldUser => {
  if(oldUser.id === user.id){
    user.updated = 'grade';
    return user
  }else{
     return oldUser
  }
});
```

but seeing array of object within array of object, I guess my map messed up

Comment: Your code seems to do what you describe. Please provide a working code with the error and expected output

Answer (score 1):

A working example (where `users` simulate `this.users` and `user` `this.user`):

```
let users = [{id:'foo'}, {id:'bar'}];
const user = {id:'bar'};

users = users.map((oldUser) => (user.id === oldUser.id) ? Object.assign({}, oldUser, {updated:'grade'}) : oldUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want this ( if ids are unique) :

```
user.updated="grade";
this.users[this.users.findIndex(u=>u.id===user.id)]=user;
```

Much better then remapping all users...

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment that's why I m writing in answer.
**map function** can't be used on object. To use map function you should convert object into an array then you can use map.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Code:

```js
const users = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],
      user = {id: 1};
      
users.map((u) => u.id === user.id ? (u.updated = 'grade') : u);
console.log(users);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```